# How does the force given by bi-polar stepper motor relate to the delay between the steps?

Tags: stepper-motor, torque, atxmega

We are using the following Bi-polar motor.(Haydon Kerk 25343-05).

https://prototypes.haydonkerk.com/ecatalog/can-stack-linear-actuator/en/linear-actuator-25343-05

You will find the specs of the motor in the above link.
There is a micro-controller which drives the motor. The motor is rotating in clockwise and anti-clockwise directions with the below pattern given at the micro-controller GPIOs.

0101->1001->1010->0110->0101... the motor will rotate one direction and for

0101->0110->1010->1001->0101... it will go the other way.

If I add a delay between steps, it rotates slower. But does it increase the force exerted by the motor or decrease the force? How is the force given by the motor relate to the delay between the steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the "Resources" tab on the URL you provided, you will find the [link](https://prototypes.haydonkerk.com/pdf/linear_actuator_25343-05.pdf) for the Performance Curve pdf.

Look at the "Thrust vs full steps per second" graph, I copied the image here:

[image]

Comment: It means - less delay between steps correspond to less thrust and more delay between steps correspond to more thrust?

Comment: Yes. Less delay = more steps per time. More delay, less steps per time.

Comment: It means, a slow rotating motor generate more thrust than a fast rotating motor right?

Comment: Yes, inside the 100 to 600 steps per second range thats what the graph indicates.

Comment: Can you explain what is chopper drive and L/R drive? What kind of mass is driven using 80 Newton for example? We have a viscous liquid which need to be ejected out of a container.

Comment: see: http://www.haydonkerk.com/?TabId=70 L/R is most likely what you are using.. 80N ~= 8kg force

Answer (score 0):

The phrasing of the question is misleading. The force exerted by a stepper motor rotating at constant speed depends only on the load it is moving. However, there is a certain *maximum* amount of force the motor can apply, and that decreases with the speed it is rotating (see Wesley Lee's answer). So a slowly moving motor can move loads that wouldn't move if you tried to make it go faster by decreasing the delay between the steps.

If your load requires, say, 10N at 200 steps/sec, 20N at 400 steps/s, and 60N at 600 steps/s, the motor would be exerting 10N if you set it to 200 steps/sec, 20N if you set it to 400 steps/s, and wouldn't move at all if you set it to 600 steps/s (with force being applied erratically forward and backward).